# How to create simple module in magento 2

Tags: magento2, module, extensions

I'm new to magento2.

I want to **create simple Hello World module** in magento 2.

How to create this module?

Comment: Sounds to me like someone can't use a search engine or is too lazy to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well this is a broad question but my best advice would be to **check the official Magento 2 samples.**

You can find them here: https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples

> This project is a collection of samples to demonstrate technologies introduced in Magento 2. You will find the most simple extension along with samples that incrementally add features to lead you through a exploration and education of the Magento 2 platform.

On top of that you can find many tutorials if you search "magento 2 create module" in Google

Answer (score 10):

Let's name the module `StackExchange_HelloWorld`.
you will need these files:

`app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/registration.php` - the registration file

```
<?php 
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'StackExchange_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

`app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml` - the module declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="StackExchange_HelloWorld" setup_version="2.0.0" />
</config>
```

`app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml` - the frontend routing file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="helloworld" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="StackExchange_HelloWorld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

`app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Index.php` - the index controller

```
<?php 
namespace StackExchange\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
     protected $resultPageFactory;
     public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
         $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
         $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Hello World'));
         return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

`app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/view/frontend/layout/helloworld_index_index.xml` - the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="StackExchange_HelloWorld::index.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

`app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/view/frontend/templates/index.phtml` - the template for the block

```
 <h2>Hello World</h2>
```

after you are done, run this in the console

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

You should be able to see the result at the url `[ROOT]/helloworld`

Comment: Thanks @Marius. I have tried this. It is not working. Shows 404 error.

Comment: is your module enabled? Does it appear in system->configuration ?

Comment: yes. enabled and showing in system->configuration.

Comment: OK. i will try again and edit the answer if needed.

Comment: I think I found the problem. The `routes.xml` file should be placed in `app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/etc/frontend` not in `app/code/StackExchange/HelloWorld/frontend`. There was an `etc` missing. And I forgot 2 `use` clauses in the controller file. See my update answer.

Comment: How to enable and disable frontend routing?

Answer (score 1):

I also just tried yesterday and succeeded to make my own hello world magento 2 module. I followed [this tutorial to create a simple Magento 2 module](http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-build-hello-world-magento-2-module-from-scratch), there are 6 steps as below

**=> Step 1: Make module folder:**

> app/code/Magentoexplorer/Helloworld

**=> Step 2: Add module.xml to declear the module**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magentoexplorer_Helloworld" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

**=> Step 3: Create registration.php to register the module**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magentoexplorer_Helloworld',
    __DIR__
);
```

**=> Step 4: How to Install, Enable or Disable/remove the module**

```
cd [magento_directory]
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**=> Step 5: Route of the module.
create `app/code/Magentoexplorer/Helloworld/etc/frontend/routes.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="magentoexplorer" frontName="helloworld">
            <module name="Magentoexplorer_Helloworld" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**=> Step 6: Controller and action.**

> app/code/Magentoexplorer/Helloworld/Index/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Magentoexplorer\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

class Display extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context)
  {
    return parent::__construct($context);
  }

  public function execute()
  {
    echo 'Hello World';
    exit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best module for you to follow would be this one: https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-newpage

It's focused on the frontend for Magento 2. You can maybe use this module and transform it into your own module.

Answer (score 0):

The most bare module is easy enough:

- Inside `app/code` create your folder for Vendor and Module. I.e. `app/code/MyCompany/FirstModule`
- Inside the `FirstModule` folder add a `registration.php`

  DIR
  );
- Inside the same folder, create an `etc` folder, like `app/code/MyCompany/FirstModule/etc`
- In the `etc` folder create a `module.xml`

And voila. That's it. You can now activate your module via SSH with the `bin/magento module:enable MyCompany_FirstModule` command.

Answer (score 0):

To create module in Magento 2, folowing steps are required:

1. Create directories.
2. Configuration of Module
3. Registration of Module
4. Front End Router File
5. Create Controller
6. Create Block
7. Frontend layout File
8. Frontend Template File
9. Module Activation

Answer (score 0):

Below is the tutorial for simple module

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

You can also download below module

https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule

There are lots of module creator available for Magento 2. Here are some links

http://cedcommerce.com/magento-2-module-creator/

https://amasty.com/magento-2-module-creator.html

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

## To create Hello World module in Magento 2.

***For Best Use PHP Storm***

#### To create Hello World module, you need to complete the following high-level steps:

***Best Practice Use PHP Storm***

Step 1: Create the folder of Hello World module

Step 2: Create module

Step 3:  Register the Created Module

Step 4: Enable the module

#### Step 1: Create Folder of HelloWorld

Name of the module is defined as “VendorName_ModuleName”. First part is name of the vendor and last part is name of the module: For example: Sathya_HelloWorld.

##### *create file directory as*

```
Magento2/app/code/Sathya/HelloWorld
```

#### Step 2: Create Module

*it is necessary to create etc folder and add the module.xml file*

```
app/code/Sathya/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml
```

Contents would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Sathya_HelloWorld" setup_version="1.0.0">
   </module>
</config>
```

#### Step 3 : Register the Created Module

*Create Registration.php file*

```
 app/code/Sathya/HelloWorld/registration.php
```

Contents would be:

```php
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Sathya_HelloWorld',
    __DIR__
);
```

#### Step 4: Enable the module

Before enable the Module make sure whether the Module is created or not. For that run the command from the Magento root directory as.

```
 php bin/magento module:status
```

It Lists all the Disabled Modules

######  Sathya_HelloWorld

To enable the Module run the command as:

```
 php bin/magento module:enable Sathya_HelloWorld
```

Also there is an another way to enable it. Which will be  explained later.

Please upgrade your database: Run “bin/magento setup:upgrade” from the Magento root directory.

Let run the command:

```
  php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Please run

```
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Then run **(optional)**

```
  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

To add route, it is necessary to create ***routes.xml*** file

```
app/code/Sathya/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/routes.xml
```

Content would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="helloworld" id="helloworld">
            <module name="Sathya_HelloWorld"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

The directory and file you need to create is:

```
app/code/Sathya/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Test.php
```

Contents would be:

```
<?php
namespace Sathya\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "Hello World";
        exit;
    }
}
```

After completed, please run command  to clear cache

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

Check your Module by entering  URL now should be as:

```
 http://< YourDomain.com >/helloworld/index/test
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy example to start with custom module.
https://learn2code2web.com/2020/12/14/magento-2-custom-module-development/

Answer (score 0):

To create a "Hello, World!" module in Magento 2, you will need to follow these steps:

Create a module directory structure:
First, you will need to create a directory structure for your module. The recommended structure is as follows:

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/
```

├── composer.json
├── etc
│   ├── module.xml
├── registration.php

Vendor and Module should be replaced with your own vendor and module names, respectively.
The composer.json file is used to manage dependencies for your module.
The etc directory will contain the module.xml file, which is used to declare your module to Magento.
The registration.php file is used to register your module with Magento.
Create the module.xml file:
In the etc directory, create a file named module.xml with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

Replace Vendor and Module with your own vendor and module names.