# How to override Pdf Invoice in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, overrides, invoice

**Magento 2:**

I was looking to add a custom text on the footer in pdf invoice. I have done this by adding a small piece of code here in this file

`vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`

I know it's not good to edit core files, so how can i override this file?

I tried by placing the same file with directories in `app/code/Local/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php` but not working.

Answer (score 2):

Seem that you tried to follow the Magento 1 way. In Magento 2, there are no `local`, `community` code pool.

We need to use [Dependency injection](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html) to override the class.

*app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice"
                type="Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice"/>
</config>
```

*app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php*

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Order\Pdf;

class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
  //Your custom code lines
}
```

---

**Recommended way**: We can use Plugin to modify the behaviour of methods in Magento 2: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: I have tried with same but not working. 
app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php in this file i override the getpdf function.

 public function getPdf($invoices = [])
 {
  $this->_drawFooter($page);   
  $this->_afterGetPdf();
  return $pdf;
 }

    protected function _drawFooter(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
    {
       $this->y =70;
       $page->drawText("Tel: +123 456 676", 230, $this->y, 'UTF-8');
    }

Comment: You know how to create a custom module in Magento 2? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122287/how-to-create-simple-module-in-magento-2

Comment: We can use Plugin: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html.

Comment: @WaqasShakeel we need to learn more about Magento 2. Magento 2 is a big application. We need to spend more time to understand Magento system. The good place to start is : http://devdocs.magento.com/

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2.3.5 you have to:

- Create your own module in /app/code (example: Vendor/PdfInvoice )
- Create a file in Vendor/PdfInvoice/registration.php
- Create a file in Vendor/PdfInvoice/etc/di.xml
- Create a file in Vendor/PdfInvoice/etc/module.xml
- Override the section concerned without forgeting to mention in your di.xml
- Disable cache ( `bin/magento cache:disable` )
- Activate your new module:
  `bin/magento module:enable Vendor_PdfInvoice` & `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- Enable cache ( `php bin/magento cache:enable` )
- Disco