# Directory of custom block in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, custom-block

I create a file custom block php.

Directory is: *`app\design\frontend\Vendor\default\Magento_Theme\Block\CustomBlock.php`*

**CustomBlock.php:**

```
class CustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\Information $storeInfo,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_storeInfo = $storeInfo;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
}
```

Define **block xml**:

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\CustomBlock" name="...">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Theme::html/footer/footer.phtml</argument>
            </block>
```

But I get an exception:

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Theme\Block\CustomBlock
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Theme\Block\CustomBlockdoes not exist
```

Please help me!

Comment: Try accepting the answer if your question is answered and working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create simple module in magento 2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122287/how-to-create-simple-module-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

you are not supposed to create block in theme directory. Instead create your own module And put you custom block there.

You block path should be something like this.

`app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\CustomBlock.php`

**EDIT:**
Module will be yours module not **Magento_Theme**.

You can get so many tutorials on the internet how to create module in magento2.

You can refer this [How to create simple module in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122287/how-to-create-simple-module-in-magento-2)

Comment: I create app\code\Vendor\Magento_Theme\Block\CustomBlock.php. But it's not working

Comment: Thask you so much. It's working!

Answer (score 0):

Just clear `var/generation` folder. And give write permissions to var again.
Make sure in your customblock.php you have defined namespace.
Then try to run your code it will work.
For every class there is a cache generated inside generation folder for reflection ,factory, interceptor and proxy classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link for creating a custom block https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/view-block-layout-template-magento-2.html

Comment: Thask you so much. It's working!