# Add customer custom-attribute in the customer address edit form and save DB

Tags: magento2

How to add a new field to this section and save DB:
[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To create an customer address attribute you need to create a module, I am assuming that you know hot create a module in `Magento2`. If not please follow some blogs or this [links](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/) or [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122287/how-to-create-simple-module-in-magento-2)

after creating module, you can use this code in your `InstallData` or `UpgradeData`

```
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

  /**
     * Customer setup factory
     *
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }
```

Now you can use this like,

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
 */
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $setup->startSetup();


    $attributesInfo = [
        'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE)ID' => [
            'label' => 'YOUR ATTRIBUTE LABEL',
            'type' => 'static',
            'input' => 'text',
            'position' => 140,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
        ]
    ];

    foreach ($attributesInfo as $attributeCode => $attributeParams) {
        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode, $attributeParams);
    }
    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

Comment: I have try. And add new field to front-end , but can not save DB.
Can you describe more?

Comment: I think in question you asked to how to create a new field in customer address, @baovic

Comment: and If you are facing an Issue with saving its data then try to clear cache and di:compile @baovic

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Comment: Thank Keyur Shah, I have try to clear cache and di, but not change.

Comment: app\design\frontend[Package_name][Theme_name]\template\customer\address\edit.phtml
But it does not work because do not see this: $block->getAddress()->getDepartment(). 
And not save in DB.

Comment: <input type="text" name="department" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getAddress()->getDepartment()) ?>" title="<?php echo __('department') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('department') ?>" id="department">

Comment: accept the answer if you find it  helpful @baovic