# Magento2 : Where do I start and what do I need?

Tags: magento2, module, web-services, integration

I want to extend a Magento 2 application with communication to a remote webservice.

The requirement is simple: When Productdata gets updated, I want to send a request to a webservice. Depending on the result of the request, I want to update a custom field of the product.

I just don't know how to get this started. Do I need to build a module? Do I need to configure a integration? Is it both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it's better to use [observer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html). In your case, you should use observer `catalog_product_save_after`. So now:

1. Create a new module, let's say Vendor_Module. I assume you know how to create a module. If not, refer to [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122291/42656).
2. Create file `app\code\Vendor\Module\etc\frontend\events.xml` with the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
       <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
           <observer name="call_sample_api" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\UpdateProduct"/>
       </event>
   </config>
   ```
3. Create file `app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\UpdateProduct.php` with the following content:

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

   use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
   use \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl;

   class UpdateProduct implements ObserverInterface {
       //Your API details
       protected $APIAddress = '<Your API address>';

       /**
        * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl
        */
       protected $curl;

       /**
        * @param Curl $curl
        */
       public function __construct(
           Curl $curl
       ) {
           $this->curl = $curl;
       }

       public function execute(Observer $observer) {
           //I assume you use get method
           $url = $this->APIAddress;
           $product = $observer->getProduct();
           //Load Product Attributes
           $params = [
               'product_attr_1' => $product->getData('product_attr_1'),
               'product_attr_2' => $product->getData('product_attr_2'),
               //And so on if you have
           ];
           //I assume you use POST method
           $this->curl->post($url, $params);
           //Do rest of your works if applicable

       }
   }
   ```

   Note: [This](https://webkul.com/blog/use-curl-magento-2/) is the method to use cURL in Magento.

Comment: THX for this detailed answer! That should help a lot! I'll try this when I'm home!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to create a module which hooks into `catalog_product_save`

> (check the magento2 event list) event.

So that when product is updated via admin you module gets in action and based on the webservice result update your custom field.