# Magento 2: Update custom div content after ajax add to cart

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, ajaxaddtocart

I want to **`update the content of a custom div when a user adds a product to cart via Ajax`**.

By using observer I am able to do this when I am not using Ajax Add to Cart functionality, but with Ajax Add to Cart, I could not make it happen.

Can anyone help me accomplish my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult. This method can trigger JS codes after adding product to cart:

1. Create a new module. I assume you know how to create a module. If not, refer to [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122291/42656). The name of module is Vendor_Module in my example.
2. Create a new layout file `catalog_product_view.xml` under `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/` with the following content:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
               <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Product" name="module_product" template="Vendor_Module::product/head.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
           </referenceBlock>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```
3. Create an empty Block file `Product.php` under `app/code/Vendor/Module/Block` with the following content:

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

   class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
   {

       public function __construct(
           \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
           array $data = [])
       {
           parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create new template `head.phtml` under `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/` with the following content:

   ```
   <script type="text/x-magento-init">
   {
       "#product_addtocart_form": {
           "CustomAddToCart": {
               //Depends on your need, you may add parameter inside here
           }
       }
   }
   </script>
   ```
5. Create `requirejs-config.js` under `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/` with the following content:

   ```
   var config = {
       map: {
           '*': {
               'CustomAddToCart': 'Vendor_Module/js/CustomAddToCart'
           }
       }
   };
   ```
6. Finally, create JS file `CustomAddToCart.js` under `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/`  with the following content:

   ```
   define([
       'jquery',
       'jquery/ui',
       'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
   ], function($){
       "use strict";

       $.widget('Vendor.CustomAddToCart', $.mage.catalogAddToCart, {
           submitForm: function(form) {
               //Run your JS codes
           }
       });
       return $.Vendor.CustomAddToCart;
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I want to show a custom dynamic message after the product has been added to the cart using ajax add to cart.