# how to check if product is already in cart

Tags: cart, addtocart, magento2.2

I am creating certain group of products which has one quantity for each product. So, I want to disable the **`Add to Cart`** button if that same product is in cart and change the text of the button to **`Already in Cart`**. 
How can I achieve this??
I am using magento 2.2

Any help/suggestion is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: have you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this in list.phtml:-

```
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session')->getQuote();
$result = $cart->getAllVisibleItems();
$itemsIds = array();
foreach ($result as $cartItem) {
    array_push($itemsIds, $cartItem->getProduct()->getId());
}

print_r(in_array($productId, $itemsIds));
```

As an alternative you can also use Magento default feature:-

> For individual settings, go to product details
>
> Click Advanced Inventory
>
> Maximum allowed inventory, and make it 1

Comment: Can you please provide me the path to list.phtml??

Comment: It is located here:-

vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml

But you will need to create a small module, and override it something like:-

app/design/frontend/Companyname/Module/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Comment: I am using a theme. Will this effect because of that?

Comment: Logically you should do it by creating a theme of your own and making the theme which you are using as a parent theme. And hence change in that child theme. Such that in future is your theme gets updated this change does not get impacted.

Comment: ok I am a Noob here. So i apologize for asking silly questions. But in which section do I put the above code in

`vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\produc‌​t\list.phtml`

Comment: I think you should follow this thread, answer by @Marius

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122287/how-to-create-simple-module-in-magento-2

You do not need to worry about controller in your case,  composer.json, registration.php and module.xml should be sufficient for you and then once these 3 files are created, just copy paste your list.phtml from vendor into the path shared above of your module

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71847/discussion-between-ratul-keot-and-dev-67commerce).

Answer (score 1):

You can check product exist or not in Quote by below code.

```
protected $checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
     }

$yourProductId = ''; //Add your product Id here

$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->hasProductId($yourProductId);
```

Comment: I have multiple products with quantity=1. Will this work for all? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the **hasProductId** function to check if a product is available in the cart or not.
2. You should use the session factory to get the checkout session.
3. Don't use the objectManager directly. Use dependency injection.

   ```
   private $checkoutSession;

   public function __construct(
       \Magento\Checkout\Model\SessionFactory $checkoutSession
   ) {
       $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
   }

   .....
   .....
   $productId = "1"; // Add your product id

   if ($this->checkoutSession->create()->getQuote()->hasProductId($productId)) {
       //product is available in the cart
   }
   ```

   }