# Magento2: How to get Cart items collection on Product view page?

Tags: magento2, cart, collection

I want to get Cart items collection on product page.

**customer-data.js**

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function ($, ko, Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.items = customerData.get('cart')().items //get cart items
            console.log(this.items);
        }
    });
});
```

**product.phtml**

```
<div class="col-md-12" data-bind="scope: 'section'" style="padding: 0;">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --> 
        <!-- ko if: items() -->
            <a class="action primary checkout" style="text-align: center;margin-top: 5px;" href="#"> Product ID</a>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "section": {
                        "component": "Codism_Customblock/js/customer-data"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Help me.

Comment: Please add code what you have tried.

Comment: If you explain your question I will answer more detailed.

Comment: Please check my code @SiarheyUchukhlebau

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the product page you can use a customer data in js:

```
require('Magento_Customer/js/customer-data').get('cart')().items
```

This is a preferred way because if you load that items on the backend (php) it will not work with a full page cache.

[image: list of items on the product view page]

---

**Update with example code:**

*Note:* full code available in [example module on GitHub](https://github.com/SiarheyUchukhlebau/MageWorx_CustomProductPage)

Here is my example based on your code:

*Adding block to the product page (for test purposes it will be place just right in the content area)*

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomProductPage/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   name="custom.product.info.cart.items"
                   template="MageWorx_CustomProductPage::cart_items.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

*Creating template with our component and configuration:*

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomProductPage/view/frontend/templates/cart_items.phtml

```
<div class="col-md-12" data-bind="scope: 'cart-items-section'" style="padding: 0;" id="cart-items-section">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "cart-items-section": {
                        "component": "MageWorx_CustomProductPage/js/cart-items"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

*Creating a component itself (`.js` part, e.g. `MageWorx_CustomProductPage/js/cart-items`):*

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomProductPage/view/frontend/web/js/cart-items.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'uiRegistry'
], function ($, ko, Component, customerData, registry) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'MageWorx_CustomProductPage/product/cart-items'
        },

        observableProperties: [
            'items'
        ],

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            var self = this;

            customerData.get('cart').subscribe(
                function (cartData) {
                    console.log(cartData);
                    self.items(cartData.items);
                }
            );

            this.items(customerData.get('cart')().items); //get cart items
            console.log(this.items());
        },

        initObservable: function () {
            this._super();
            this.observe(this.observableProperties);

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Here is some **clarifications**:

1. We use custom template named `MageWorx_CustomProductPage/product/cart-items` to render items.
2. We use customer data as a source for items.
3. Items property is observable part of our component (see `observableProperties` prop. and `initObservable` function), where all items from customer data will be stored.
4. Each time when the customer data updated we synchronize our `items` property with the items in cart (see `customerData.get('cart').subscribe` part of `init` function body).

*Adding main template:*

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomProductPage/view/frontend/web/template/product/cart-items.html

```
<div style="float: left" data-bind="visible: items().length">
    <h3 data-bind="i18n: 'Cart items template'"></h3>
    <ul>
    <!-- ko foreach: items -->
        <li>
            <!-- ko template: 'MageWorx_CustomProductPage/product/item' --><!-- /ko -->
        </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="float: left" data-bind="visible: !items().length">
    <!-- ko i18n: 'There no items in your cart' --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

*Adding a sub-template responsible for render of an each item from a cart:*

> app/code/MageWorx/CustomProductPage/view/frontend/web/template/product/item.html

```
<h3><!-- ko i18n: 'Item id: ' --><!-- /ko --><!-- ko text: item_id --><!-- /ko --></h3>
<span data-bind="text: product_name"></span>
<img data-bind="attr: {src: product_image.src, alt: product_image.alt}"/>
<span data-bind="html: product_price"></span>
```

Result with 1 item:

[image: result with 1 item in cart]

Result when adding second item:

[image: result with 2 items]

Result when all items removed through mini-cart on same page:

[image: result without items]

**PS:** do not forget to remove the `console.log()` from code when all will be done.

Comment: I will check and update you. Thanks!

Comment: The code is working...Please let me how to get cart array in phtml file.

Comment: @MasudShaikh please, add `.phtml` file to your question

Comment: Please check my .phtml and .js file

Comment: I got cart items in console.log file but how to print in .phtml file

Comment: Did you get my code?

Comment: @MasudShaikh yes, I will update my answer when got a free time.

Comment: I will be waiting for your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MasudShaikh please, check my updated answer :)

Comment: I will check and update you. Thank you so much.

Comment: This code worked properly. Thank you so much for you described in more details.

Comment: @MasudShaikh glad to help you :)

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau can u please help on this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/320623/how-to-add-cart-items-in-abandoned-cart-email-template-in-magento2