# Magento 2.2.3 I want to show how many quantity is already added for each product in category page

Tags: addtocart, full-page-cache, magento2.2.3

[image: Shows when I click add to cart(+) button]
[image: After I refresh the page]
I've added one field to show `already added qty` on the category page. 
I've made it the place next to the `add to cart` button.
When I click the `add to cart` button, it increases the `qty`. But the problem happens when I reload the page.
If I reload the page, it disappeared. Only clearing Cache, it shows again. Does FPC cause this problem?

This is the input field to show `qty` in category page.. For testing, I've set qty as 2: static value. but its not a problem because I can get it.
`/var/www/html/store/app/design/frontend/Vendor/default/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

`

```
                        $isInCart = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product\IsInCart')->isInCart($_product);

                        $productQty= "2";

                        if($isInCart){?>

                            <input type="button" value="-" data-id="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" id="subs_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" class="btn btn-default pull-left qtyminus" />

                            <input type="number"

                            name="qty"

                            id="qty_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"

                            style="width:50px;"

                            maxlength="12"

                            value="<?php echo $productQty; ?>"

                            title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"

                            /> 

                        <?php }else{?>

                            <input type="button" value="-" data-id="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" id="subs_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" class="btn btn-default pull-left qtyminus" style="display:none;"/>   

                            <input type="number"

                            name="qty"

                            id="qty_<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>"

                            style="width:50px;display:none;"

                            maxlength="12"

                            value=""

                            title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"

                            />

                        <?php } ?>`
```

And this is block controller

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Catalog\Product;

use \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\SessionFactory as CheckoutSession;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

/** Class provides method to check if given product is in cart
 * @universal
 */
class IsInCart extends Template
{

    /**
     * @var CheckoutSession
     */
    private $checkoutSession;
    /**
     * Di.
     * @param CheckoutSession $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    /**
     * Method check if provided product is in cart of current customer.
     * Doesn't work dynamically.
     * TODO: There is a bug actually in magento connected with session and full page cache
     * TODO: More details: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3294
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product
     *
     * @return bool $inCart
     */
    public function isInCart(ProductInterface $product)
    {
        $productId = $product->getId();
        // $cartItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        // $itemsIds = array();
        // $productQty = "";
        // foreach ($cartItems as $cartItem) {
        //     $itemsIds[] = $cartItem->getProduct()->getId();
        //     $productQty= $cartItem->getQty();
        // }

        // return in_array($productId, $itemsIds);
        If ($this->checkoutSession->create()->getQuote()->hasProductId($productId)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the code even located? Please add the paths

Comment: This needs to be done via javascript or in .phtml if you disable full_page cache but I don't recommend  that.

Comment: *"If I reload the page, it disappeared"*
What disapeared? The page??

Comment: `qty` input field, I meant. Because $isInCart becomes `false` after I refresh the page. Is this something you wanted to know? @Black.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in the way you think.

Category page is a cacheble page.

The value you are trying to retrieve is not a cacheable one, so the only way to do this in .phtml would be to disable full_page cache, but I don't recommend it.

To do this in valid way, you need to create a javascript component, and use customer-data related to cart.

Here you got an example of how to make a component which retrieves holds data of cart.

[Magento2: How to get Cart items collection on Product view page?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301886/magento2-how-to-get-cart-items-collection-on-product-view-page)

After that you need to use javascript to populate the value in all your products.