# send Observer data to phtml file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, blocks

I am trying to send Observer info into the block file. used the add to cart event as like below.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
      <observer name="event_observer_checkoutcartproductaddafterwe" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Checkoutcartproductaddafter" />
  </event>
</config>
```

Then

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/Checkoutcartproductaddafter.php**

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
 class Checkoutcartproductaddafter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
 {
  protected $layout;
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Layout $layout)
   {
    $this->layout = $layout;
   }
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {     
    $event = $observer->getEvent();         
    $eventData = $event->getData('quote_item');
    $item = ($eventData->getParentItem() ? $eventData->getParentItem() : $eventData);
    $product = $item->getProduct();
    $productId = $product->getId();
      $prepareJson = array(
             'Added To Cart' => array(
             'productId' => $productId,
             'productName' => $product->getName(),                    
          )
        );
     $block = $this->layout->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Index\Index')->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::before-body-end.phtml')
        ->setObserverData($prepareJson)
        ->toHtml();
     }
   }
```

**Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/before-body-end.phtml**

```
<?php 
 $jsonData = $block->getObserverData();
?>
<script id='test_script' type='text/javascript'>
  console.log('inside');
  var data = '<?php echo $jsonData; ?>';
  console.log('--data--',data);
</script>
```

From the above code I am able to pass the observer data into the phtml file, but I am trying to print the received info into the browser console.

Once printed in browser i have to send to a third party tool using javascript function.

The problem is whatever js is written That's not working. Please help me how can we achieve this. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: what about the local storage? cart items/info is normally available in it

Comment: @SantiBM, yes, this is one event i mentioned above, like that I have to make for all major events in magento2(order. delete cart, invoice, shipment, customer_login) etc..

Comment: @SantiBM, please update your answer

Comment: hi! try this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301886/magento2-how-to-get-cart-items-collection-on-product-view-page I'm not sure why you need to use an observer if your goal is to have the data in the console

Comment: @SantiBM, bcz i have to send the info to third party tool using javascript. so I am sending data from all the events, that i can get it in phtml, a javascript function is written in phtml to take this data recieved from observer. \

Comment: @SantiBM, The suggested link is not relevant to my requirement.

Comment: in phtml have you first check it will give the data what you set from observer?

Comment: Yes I am getting data in phtml which is set in observer, but the javascript written in phtml not working, not even console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **define same observer into  below event.**

```
   <event name="controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view">
       <observer name="send_data2" instance="Vendorename\Modulename\Observer\Yourfilename" />
   </event>
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
       <observer name="send_data1" instance="Vendorename\Modulename\Observer\Yourfilename" />
   </event>
```

> **Add into your Observer file**

```
protected $resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(
    .............................................................
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    .............................................................

) {
    ................................................
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    ...............................................
}
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    ob_start();
    $rowData = "your custom data"; // you can add object json array any kind of data
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');

    // retrieve quote items collection
    $itemsCollection = $cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();

    // get array of all items what can be display directly
    $itemsVisible = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

    $data = [];
    $x = 0;
    foreach($itemsVisible as $item) {
        $data[$x]['name'] = $item->getName();
        $data[$x]['sku'] = $item->getSku();
        $data[$x]['qty'] = $item->getQty();
        $x++;
      }
    $phtml_data = json_encode($data);

    $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(\Vendorname\Modulename\Block\CustomBlock::class)
            ->setData('customdata', $phtml_data)
            ->setTemplate("Vendorname_Modulename::customdata.phtml")->toHtml();
    echo $block;
}
```

> **Add into your phtml file**

```
<?php
$data = $block->getData('customdata');
print_r($data);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
console.log("<?php echo $data; ?>");
</script>
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Hi @msquare, yes I can get observer data in phtml but the JavaScript written in phtml not working, pls check my question.

Comment: @jafarpinjar check into console observe data are printed. please check and update me..

Comment: hi @msquare, yes i checked it, console its not printing

Comment: i update file please check and update me.

Comment: Have you checked @jafarpinjar ?

Comment: yes checked it, page is getting refreshed on observer call, so $data getting empty on refresh

Comment: now data are update after page refresh please check and update me.

Comment: Need to avoid page refresh, @mahesh, as i am loading template file in every pages

Comment: hi @Msquare why two events here?

Comment: @Msquare,If I add or echo anything in observer, I get this error: https://prnt.sc/z94fRrJx5M27. I tried with your way and  $layout = $this->layoutFactory->create();
        $block = $layout->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')->setTemplate('ABCD_XYZ::custom.phtml');
        $response = $observer->getEvent()->getData('response');
        $response
            ->setHeader('Content-Type','text/html')
            ->setBody($block->toHtml());