# How to execute javascript code and pass to it some values after an event is triggered?

Tags: magento2, javascript, event-observer, phtml

I'm trying to execute some javascript code and pass to it some values after an event (e.g. **Add to Cart event**) is triggered. To be more specific I'd like to pass:

- All logged customer details (Firstname, Lastname, Email, etc.)
- Cart details (Product ID, Product Name, amount, price, etc.)

In order to do that, I create my own module like this:

**Vendor/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0.0" active="true" />
</config>
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
   <event name="checkout_cart_save_after"> 
      <observer name="checkout_cart_save_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\AddToCart" /> 
   </event>
</config>
```

...and here I don't know how to move forward...

**Vendor/Module/Observer/AddToCart.php**

```
<?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
 
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
 
    class AddToCart implements ObserverInterface
    {
        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

        }
 
    }
```

I think I should get cart and customer details in some way, then pass them to a view (E.g. Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/add_to_cart.pthml) and execute inside it my Javascript code. Am I wrong? How should I proceed?

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/325623/82670

Comment: @Msquare thanks, I already saw that answer but I honestly don't understand exactly how to do. Could you elaborate better the answer?

Comment: Rather than try and load JS after you add to cart with PHP, why not just use JS to add to cart to begin with?

Comment: @BenCrook I don't know. Maybe it could be better than this approach. Could you show me how?

Comment: @Msquare I don't have any block in my module. Following that example it says: `$block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(\Vendorname\Modulename\Block\CustomBlock::class)
            ->setData('customdata', $phtml_data)
            ->setTemplate("Vendorname_Modulename::customdata.phtml")->toHtml();`. Where should I point `->createBlock(\Vendorname\Modulename\Block\CustomBlock::class)`?

Comment: @BenCrook What I'm basically trying to do is implementing `Sendinblue Automation` ( https://tracker-doc.sendinblue.com/docs/advanced-features#section-track-events ) to track the cart events and send customer info.

Comment: @KaMZaTa  if you do not have any block please use this class Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

Comment: @Msquare could you please post a complete module code? I'm not able to make it work.