# How can I send data from observer to block and I want to retrieve from block to phtml in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I created an event in custom module admin . After caling event need to send data from observer to phtml page on admin side in Magento 2

Comment: check this out - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325312/send-observer-data-to-phtml-file-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

Kindly integrate the provided code into your observer to fetch your data in the phtml file.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
) 
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
$block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(\Vendor\Module\Block\CustomBlock::class)
            ->setData('custom', $yourdata)
            ->setTemplate("Vendor_Module::custom.phtml")->toHtml();
}
```

Subsequently, retrieve this data in the phtml file and utilize it to configure the block accordingly.

```
$block->getData('custom');
```

Comment: Ok thank you will check