# How to create core module for my other modules?

Tags: magento2

I need to know how to create a core module for dependency of other my modules? Like so: amasty_core amasty_layerednavigation that layered navigation needs core module.

I need it on Magento 2.1.9

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your module's dependency declaration should look something like this:

**File** - `module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="YourVendorName_YourModuleName" setup_version="X.Y.Z">
        <sequence>
            <module name="amasty_core"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you. could you please give me full package? all files and folders...

Comment: yes can you check  below link:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/122287/how-to-create-simple-module-in-magento-2